# VB.NET - Como ordenar um DataGridView por cor

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Tenho um DataGridView, onde eu faço uma crítica de documento. O DataGridView é preenchido por um arquivo, eu uso o `OpenFileDialog` para selecionar o arquivo e preencher o DataGridView. Em seguida eu chamo uma função onde é feita uma crítica pelo campo do CNPJ/CPF, atribuindo cores às linhas do grid:
 - Cinza: Cancelados;
 - Vermelho: Devolvidos;
 - Verde: Sempre entregue;
 - Amarelo: Entregue/Devolvido;
 - Branco: Primeiro registro.

Eu já tenho uma função feita onde eu verifico as críticas do documento, porém fica um carnaval dentro do DataGridView. Segue o exemplo na imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria saber se tem uma forma de eu organizar esse DataGridView por cor, primeiro todas as linhas de cor cinza, depois as linhas vermelhas, depois as verdes, em seguida as linhas amarelas e por fim todas as linhas brancas.

Segue meu código atual:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class salvar_arquivo
    Dim sqlcoon = New MySqlConnection '' conexao
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    Private datagrid As New DataTable
    ' load do form
    Private Sub salvar_arquivo_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '' carrega todo os monitoramento do banco de dados cad_monitoramento
    Dim datagrid As New DataTable
    ' INSERE COLUNAS NO GRIDVIEW
    datagrid.Columns.Add("Identificação")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("Protocolo")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("Destinatario")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("Endereço")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("Bairro")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("Cep")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("Data")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("CNPF/CPF")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("Situacao")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("Cliente")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("data_processamento")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("data_vencimento")
        datagrid.Columns.Add("numeracao")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = datagrid
        ' inserindo o a largura das colunas

        ' deixando invisivel a coluna do banco de dados
        DataGridView1.Columns("Situacao").Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns("Cliente").Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns("data_processamento").Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns("data_vencimento").Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns("numeracao").Visible = False
    ' ORDENAS OS TITULOS DA COLUNA NO CENTRALIZADO
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(7).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(8).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(9).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(10).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(11).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(12).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter


        txtcod.Select()
    End Sub

    ' butao selecionar e ler arquivo
    Private Sub btnarquivo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnarquivo.Click
        selecionar()

End Sub


    ' Função para ler o arquivo linha por linha separado por tab
    Private Sub selecionar()
        abrir.ShowDialog()
        '  Dim x As String = ("62210980259, 10507378001020")
        Dim separador As Char

        Dim dr As DataRow
    ' INSERE COLUNAS NO GRIDVIEW
    Try

            datagrid.Columns.Add("Identificação")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("Protocolo")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("Destinatario")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("Endereço")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("Bairro")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("Cep")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("Data")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("CNPF/CPF")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("Situacao")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("Cliente")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("data_processamento")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("data_vencimento")
            datagrid.Columns.Add("numeracao")

            DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
            DataGridView1.AutoResizeRows()

            dr = datagrid.NewRow()

        '
        ' FAZ A LEITURA DO ARQUIVO - COM EXPAÇAMENTO POR TAB
        Dim arquivo As New System.IO.StreamReader(abrir.FileName)
            separador = vbTab
            ' faz um split de leitura de linha a linha do arquivo
            While arquivo.Peek() <> -1
                datagrid.Rows.Add(arquivo.ReadLine().Split(separador))
            End While
            DataGridView1.DataSource = datagrid

            TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount.ToString
        '
        ' chama a função de critica do arquivo colocando cores nas linhas de acordo com a sentaça
        relacionar_cnpj()


        '
    Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("ex.Message")

        End Try
    End Sub

' click f2 para abrir o form de pesquisa de selecionar cliente 
Private Sub txtcod_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtcod.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.F2 Then

    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub salvar_arquivo_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If AscW(e.KeyChar) = 27 Then  ' vbKeyReturn = Tecla Esc
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub


Private Sub salvar_arquivo_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    txtcod.Clear()
    txtrazao.Clear()
End Sub

' funcção de critica do arquivo - cada sentença mostra uma cor diferente no grid.
Private Sub relacionar_cnpj()
    Dim COMMAND2 As MySqlCommand
    Using sqlcoon As MySqlConnection = GetConnectionMySQL()

        Try
            Dim READER2 As MySqlDataReader


            sqlcoon.Open()

            For r As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim Query As String
                Query = "select cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf,cnpjcpf_entregue,cnpjcpf_devolvido,cnpjcpf_cancelado from speed.cnpjcpf where cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf ='" & DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(7).Value.ToString() & "'"

                COMMAND2 = New MySqlCommand(Query, sqlcoon)
                READER2 = COMMAND2.ExecuteReader


                While READER2.Read
                    Dim cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf = READER2.GetString("cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf")
                    Dim cnpjcpf_entregue = READER2.GetString("cnpjcpf_entregue")
                    Dim cnpjcpf_devolvido = READER2.GetString("cnpjcpf_devolvido")
                    Dim cnpjcpf_cancelado = READER2.GetString("cnpjcpf_cancelado")

                    ' se for a primeira vez do registro do cnpj
                    If cnpjcpf_entregue = "N" And cnpjcpf_devolvido = "N" And cnpjcpf_cancelado = "N" Then

                        DataGridView1.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White

                        ' se for devolvido
                    ElseIf cnpjcpf_entregue = "N" And cnpjcpf_devolvido = "S" And cnpjcpf_cancelado = "N" Then

                        DataGridView1.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.IndianRed

                        ' se for cancelado
                    ElseIf cnpjcpf_entregue = "N" And cnpjcpf_devolvido = "S" And cnpjcpf_cancelado = "S" Then

                        DataGridView1.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Silver

                        ' se for sempre entregue
                    ElseIf cnpjcpf_entregue = "S" And cnpjcpf_devolvido = "N" And cnpjcpf_cancelado = "N" Then

                        DataGridView1.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen
                        ' se for entregue e ja volto como devolvido (Ambos)
                    ElseIf cnpjcpf_entregue = "S" And cnpjcpf_devolvido = "S" And cnpjcpf_cancelado = "N" Then

                        DataGridView1.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        ' se for entregue e ja volto como devolvido e cancelado 
                    ElseIf cnpjcpf_entregue = "S" And cnpjcpf_devolvido = "S" And cnpjcpf_cancelado = "S" Then

                        DataGridView1.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        End If


                End While

                READER2.Close()
            Next

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally

            sqlcoon.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma coluna *unbound* no seu grid e chama-la de "IndiceCor", por exemplo, e você atribuiria números na ordem que você quer que as cores apareçam:

- IndiceCor = 1 -> Linhas de cor cinza;
- IndiceCor = 2 -> Linhas de cor vermelha;
- IndiceCor = 3 -> Linhas de cor verde;
- IndiceCor = 4 -> Linhas de cor amarela;
- IndiceCor = 5 -> Linhas de cor branca;

E depois organizaria o grid por essa coluna, mais ou menos assim:

```vb
DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("IndiceCor").Value = 1   'Linha Cinza.
DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("IndiceCor").Value = 2   'Linha Vermelha.
DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("IndiceCor").Value = 3   'Linha Verde.
DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("IndiceCor").Value = 4   'Linha Amarela.
DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("IndiceCor").Value = 5   'Linha Branca.

'[...]

DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns("IndiceCor"), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

O problema é que dessa forma você só poderia organizar pela cor, e não poderia colocar como segunda opção o CNPJ, por exemplo. Então, outra opção seria colocar essa coluna *virtual* com o índice da cor direto em um DataTable, por exemplo, que tenha os dados da sua base, assim você poderia usar mais de um campo na organização.

Comment: Funcionou Pedro. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom Jose. A melhor forma de agradecer é marcar a minha resposta como aceita. E marcar as mensagens como  úteis, quando você tiver pontuação suficiente. Leia essa página que explica o básico do funcionamento do site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Assim que eu obter a reputação suficiente para marcas como útil eu farei sim foi de muita grande ajuda Pedro .

Comment: Legal, mas você pode aceitar a resposta desde já!  ;-)

Comment: Eu já marquei como útil :) . Seta para cima certo ?

Comment: Não, é o "tique" embaixo da seta para baixo, para aceitar a resposta!

Comment: Está Marcado Pedro . Agradeço.